# what's the difference between pointer==null and !pointer in my code?

Tags: c, if-statement, null, clion, c99

in extended_map.c I wrote:

```
#include "extended_map.h"
#include "map.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Extended_Map_t{
    char* key;
};

Extended_Map extended_mapCreate()
{
    Extended_Map extended_map = malloc(sizeof(*extended_map));
    if (!extended_map)
    {
        return NULL;//Here is the problem
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

in extended_map.h I wrote:

```
typedef struct Extended_Map_t* Extended_Map;
```

But Clion shows me the the first `return NULL` which is located inside if statement is not reachable. why is that?

Note: I think I didn't have this issue before updating to the newset version of Clion which was released today, Plus changing `!extended_map` to `extended_map==NULL` solves the issues...

Comment: No, what you need to do is present the typedef that you are hiding!  It's probably not the issue, but it is confusing to people reading the code, and the typedef is unhelpfully hiding the actual type of extended_map.  (Which, I guess, is a pointer)

Comment: I have added the code inside extended_map.h it's actually a pointer

Comment: @TomKarzes I shortened the function to make it clear, the rest of the code is not important

Comment: any suggestions please?

Comment: @TomKarzes you mentioned that we would enter the if statement if malloc fails, then why clion marked this code as unreachable?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough.  `Extended_Map` is a pointer type.  If malloc returns `NULL`, then both `extended_map == NULL` and `!extended_map` should be true.  They are equivalent.  So I don't know why Clion is complaining.  Could some other code from your original source be blocking part of the `if` statement?  Like an earlier `return` statement or something?

Comment: @TomKarzes nothing was written before this...

Comment: It could be a Clion bug.  Did you try it with `gcc`, with full warnings enabled?  It might be able to shed some light on the problem.

Comment: @TomKarzes as I mentioned changing this to ==NULL fixes the issue but I don't know why! can you kindly download and old version of clion to check if that issue happens there too? downloading one will take years given my internet speed

Comment: They are exactly the same. It is a CLion bug, you should report it. (I wasn't asked, but I can't download it either. I'm in an area where cell service is bad)

Comment: @clark_smith Sorry, but downloading and installing Clion is more than I'm willing to take on.  But `!extended_map` and `extended_map == NULL` should be equivalent.  An interesting experiment would be to replace the call to `malloc` with a call to some function that you write, like a `malloc` wrapper, and see if that changes the Clion behavior.

Comment: I can confirm: it's a bug in clion

Comment: @clark, FYI, I compiled your code with clang, and "borland classic" compilers with all warnings turned on.
I do not get any warnings.